# Отладка GWT-приложения, подключенного к удаленному серверу

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea, google-app-engine

Можно ли подключиться GWT-приложением (клиент) к удаленному серверу (`appengine`) таким образом, чтобы можно было отлаживать Java-код (дебаггер)? Среда разработки - IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вам следует создать run конфигурацию типа "Remote", а удаленный сервер запускать с дополнительными параметрами (они будут показаны в настройках конфигурации в идее).

Дополнительную информацию можно найти в справке по данному типу run конфигурации.